# CKAN/Jetty/Solr: ERROR 500: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/LocalResolver

Tags: solr, jetty, ckan

I'm installing ckan onto ubuntu server 14.04 from source following this guide: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html

The problem I'm encountering is that when I try to access solr locally I get the following error:

```
ERROR 500: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/LocalResolver.
```

I've googled and tried changing libtomcatlib-6 to a previous version but the downgrade won't take (following this here apt-get says that the version wasn't found). Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you get the following error message when opening the Solr page in your browser:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/LocalResolver
```

Then run these commands:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/share/java/tomcat-coyote.jar >> /etc/jetty/start.config'
sudo service jetty restart
```

Then reload the page and you should see the Solr admin interface.

(I'm assuming you installed Solr with Jetty as per the source install instructions, i.e. `sudo apt-get install solr-jetty openjdk-6-jdk`. The `NoClassDefFoundError` is because of a problem with Ubuntu 14.04's jetty package.)

Answer (score 3):

CKAN doesn't support Ubuntu 14.04 yet, there are a number of issues; https://github.com/ckan/ckan/labels/14.04 Install on Ubuntu 12.04. Having said that, there is a pull request here with working source install instructions for 14.04: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2020

Comment: I thought you could install from source. Is this not the case?

Comment: The source install instructions are tested on Ubuntu 12.04, not 14.04. On 14.04 there's a problem with jetty, but the pull request I linked to does contain a workaround for that and you can get it working on 14.04 by following the source install instructions in the pull request.

Comment: In the interests of putting the actual answer in Stack Overflow directly I'll add another answer...

Comment: Great, I hope ckan will soon work ok at least on ubuntu 14.04, which is a newer LTS release